# Echo php identifiers as they are i.e. syntactically!

Tags: php, string, syntax, echo

At a place in my PHP application, I need to echo PHP's Global variable's Syntactically, i.e. something of the sort
`echo "$_POST['submit']";`
But this ain't working. Can anyone please shed some light on it?

The actual piece of code is:
`echo "<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) echo 'value="'. $_POST['{$column['Field']}'] .'"'; ?>";`

Comment: maybe the variable is not set. try give more details. You question is very vague]

Comment: so tell us what is not working? are you getting an error?

Comment: herein I am trying to echo the syntax itself including that of first $_POST variable.

Comment: Yes I am getting an error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /opt/lampp/htdocs/public/userregister.php on line 34`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc)

```
$str = <<<'EOD'
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) echo 'value="'. $_POST['{$column['Field']}'] .'"'; ?>
EOD;
```

This is available from PHP 5.3 and it doesn't interpolate into string the variable value

to echo it simply do a:

```
echo $str;
```

or a

```
echo htmlentities($str);
```

Comment: you are not getting me. i want everything including those php tags to be echoed.

Answer (score 2):

This is not correct:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) echo 'value="'. $_POST['{$column['Field']}']
```

switch to this:

```
<?php 
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
 echo 'value="'. $_POST[$column['Field']];

// or 
 echo 'value="'. $_POST['submit'].'"';

?>
```

whichever is the one you need

UPDATE: from the comment.

```
echo <<<HERE_DOC
  <?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        echo 'value="'. $_POST['{$column['Field']}'] .'"'; ?>';
HERE_DOC;
```

this will echo the all the string in between the heredoc string

Read More about the [HEREDOC Syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Comment: `echo "<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) echo 'value="'. $_POST['{$column['Field']}'] .'"'; ?>";`

Comment: you are not getting me. i want everything including those php tags to be echoed.

Comment: Still the same error. NOWDOC needs to be used instead of HEREDOC.

Answer (score 1):

When echoing something complex with lots of double and single quotes you should probably use nowdoc syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Try something like:

```
echo <<<'STRING'
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) echo 'value="'. $_POST['{$column['Field']}'] .'"'; ?>
STRING;
```

You can also do this with single quotes, but you need to escape all the single quotes in your string, like:

```
echo '<?php if(isset($_POST[\'submit\'])) echo \'value="\'. $_POST[\'{$column[\'Field\']}\'] .\'"\'; ?>';
```

**Finally**, if you're outputting to HTML you need to use `htmlspecialchars()` to convert `<` to `&lt;`, '>' to `&gt;`, and `&` to `&amp;`.

```
echo htmlspecialchars(<<<'STRING'
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])) echo 'value="'. $_POST['{$column['Field']}'] .'"'; ?>
STRING
);
```

And:

```
echo htmlspecialchars('<?php if(isset($_POST[\'submit\'])) echo \'value="\'. $_POST[\'{$column[\'Field\']}\'] .\'"\'; ?>');
```

Comment: Still the same error. NOWDOC needs to be used instead of HEREDOC.

Comment: Thanks @6nagi9, I wasn't clear what he wanted to output from his original post, but I am now from is comment. I changed it to NOWDOC.